# where to enter key in code for google distance matrix

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a couple of web pages that use the Google distance. I took the sample code for javascript and HTML that Google provides and adjusted it for my purposes. They seem to say that I need an API key to use the service, but my pages work fine without it. First, is it essential to use an API key when I am hoping for a few hundred requests a day. If it is essential, where do I place the API key within the following sample code that Google provides?

```
function initialize() {
  var opts = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.53, 9.4),
    zoom: 10
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), opts);
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function calculateDistances() {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      //origins: [origin1, origin2],
    origins: [origin2],
      //destinations: [destinationA, destinationB],
    destinations,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
}

function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = '';
    deleteOverlays();

    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      addMarker(origins[i], false);
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        addMarker(destinations[j], true);
        outputDiv.innerHTML += origins[i] + ' to ' + destinations[j]
            + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in '
            + results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
      }
    }
  }
}

function addMarker(location, isDestination) {
  var icon;
  if (isDestination) {
    icon = destinationIcon;
  } else {
    icon = originIcon;
  }
  geocoder.geocode({'address': location}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        icon: icon
      });
      markersArray.push(marker);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: '
        + status);
    }
  });
}

function deleteOverlays() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markersArray = [];
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content-pane">
      <div id="inputs">
        <pre>
var origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(55.930, -3.118);
var origin2 = 'Greenwich, England';
var destinationA = 'Stockholm, Sweden';
var destinationB = new google.maps.LatLng(50.087, 14.421);
        </pre>
        <p><button type="button"      onclick="calculateDistances();">Calculate
          distances</button></p>
      </div>
      <div id="outputDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I'm aware there is no **explicit** way to insert a google maps API key into JavaScript code (I suppose you wanted to do this).

The general way to do this is to reference the key by using the standard javascript tags and put it in between them inside the **src** attribute.

Example:

```
<script>
   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=123456ABCDEFG&sensor=false" 
    </script>
```

Since your are calling your google maps using the *DomListener* the above example which calls the API key is the way to go, other then that you can also call your google maps function by using this line of code which is always shown in the google maps official docs:

```
<script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initialize">
    </script>
```

The async keyword means that the HTML (web page) doesn't have to wait for the google maps API to respond in order to render. Basically, the HTML (apart from the google maps) renders and then when the actual map is ready it will load. If you choose this, then erase the *DomListener* line of code.

The rest can be found in the official page of google maps

URL: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key